# Image building works with docker build . command, but hangs with docker compose build command

Tags: docker, docker-compose

While building an image I ran into some interesting thing: when using command `docker build . --network host` I get everything build up correctly, with no issues. On the other hand, when building the image using `docker compose build`, with `network_mode: "host"` set up or unset in the `docker-compose.yml`, the build process hangs once it reaches `RUN apk update ...` line and eventually throws connection timeout error.

The config files look in the following way:

```
FROM python:3.10-alpine3.18

COPY . .

RUN apk update && apk upgrade \
    && apk add git vim busybox \
    && pip3 install -r requirements.txt

ENTRYPOINT ["busybox"]
CMD ["crond", "-f"]
```

```yaml
version: "3.7"

services:
  mongodb:
    container_name: mongo-server
    image: mongo:6.0
    networks:
      - mynet

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express:latest
    networks:
      - mynet
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"

  repository:
    container_name: repository
    network_mode: "host"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

networks:
  mynet:
    external: true
```

I'd say it's some kind of proxy issue, but the `docker` (without `compose`) building command works. Where to look for other possible reasons it doesn't work as intended?

Comment: I'd be surprised if your application specifically needs Git, `vi`, or BusyBox to run.  (The Alpine-based image will already include BusyBox as its base in any case.)  Can you just delete the `apk` commands entirely?

Comment: Ah yes, it needs these packages, and many more (removed from the markup not to blur the whole picture).